# How to retrieve and display the same column Name from two tables in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display data from two tables with the same column name by LEFT join keyword. How will it be possible to display data from the same column name in PHP?

Retrieve from database in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `photo` as A LEFT JOIN `users` B ON (A.photo = B.users)
```

The PHP code to display below:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++){
   $date_added = $data[$i]['date_added']; 
   $date_added_2 = $data[$i]['date_added'];
```

Comment: When photos equals users, that's when things are really messed up.

Comment: You need to get into the habit of accepting answers that help you out. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the aliases...

```
SELECT A.date_added AS a_added, B.date_added AS b_added
FROM `photo` A 
LEFT JOIN `users` B 
ON (A.photo = B.users)
```

Then change the reference in your for loop.